# How to combine column groups in PrimeNg Tree table with unscrollable column?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, primeng-treetable

I'm using `primeng 7.1.3`.

What I'm trying to create is a `scrollable tree table` (horizontal and vertical) with:

- the 1st `column not scrollable`
- 2 `groups of column` excluding the 1st one

I managed to get something like this: [StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-juf8bj).

**Begin of Edit** ---------------------------------------------------

I found a way around so I have updated the Stackblitz link to correct the problem. *If you want to see the original problem*, comment the `ngAfterViewInit()` in the `app-component.ts` file. Also *updated tags* of the question because of said solution.

**End of Edit** -------------------------------------------------------

From what I understand, **it puts the 2 groups above the first column** - instead of leaving an `empty cell the size of 2 rows` - and the other columns as it should be.

Documentation for tree tables: [PrimeNg Tree Table documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable)

- [Column group](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable/colgroup)
- [Scroll](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable/scroll)

Any hint on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution but it's not very clean.

Instead of going deep in PrimeNg framework and tinkering with its code, I decided to use `ngAfterViewInit` and **work on the produced DOM**. From here, I just looked for the cells that shouldn't have been here and deleted them. I also updated the height of the empty cell.

Below is the function used in `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
correctDOM(): void {
  function cleanFixedHeader(tagName: string, element: Element): Element {
    const listElementsByTagName = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if (listElementsByTagName.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < listElementsByTagName.length - 1; i++) {
      element.removeChild(listElementsByTagName[i]);
    }
    return listElementsByTagName[listElementsByTagName.length - 1];
  }

  const treeTableFixedHead: Element = this.elRef.nativeElement
                                  .getElementsByClassName('ui-treetable-frozen-view')[0]
                                  .getElementsByClassName('ui-treetable-thead')[0];

  const treeTableFixedRow = cleanFixedHeader('TR', treeTableFixedHead);
  if (treeTableFixedRow !== null) {
    const treeTableFixedHeaderCell = cleanFixedHeader('TH', treeTableFixedRow);
    treeTableFixedHeaderCell.setAttribute('height', String(treeTableFixedHeaderCell.getBoundingClientRect().height * 2));
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-juf8bj), same as in the question. I will edit said question to indicate how to see the original issue.

Hope it'll help someone as it doesn't seem many questions are asked about PrimeNg. Still, **keep in mind that this solution is really not a clean one**. But it saved me a lot of time so...